# Change the colour in elements of the list and divide

Tags: list-manipulation, color

I have the next code:

```
u = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {11,12}}}
u = MapAt[Style[#, Blue] &, u, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}]
u[[1, 1, 2]]/u[[1, 2, 2]]
```

I want to do operation with elements of differents colours. When I change the colour to one element of the list and after I divide by other element which I have not change the colour, Mathematica not calculate. I don´t know why happens it.

Comment: How can mathematica know how to divide elements in `Style[***]` form? You'll have to write your own rules to process these operations. Also, what you want the result to be? a `1/2` styled blue or with no style?

Comment: I want that the result be with styled. In my example, u have possition [[1,2,1]] and [[1,2,2]] blue. I want only change the colour and after I can manipulated list (divide, etc...).

Comment: will my solution solve your problem?

Comment: @Wjx, your solution work very well, thank so much, but there are some cases that not work and I don´t why. When I have these list, your solution not work: a={1014.24, 4807.98} and b={\!\(\*
StyleBox["947.290786227471`",
StripOnInput->False,
LineColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1],
FrontFaceColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1],
GraphicsColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1],
FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1],
$CellContext`BackFaceColor -> RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]\), 4385.53}. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://thumbs.subefotos.com/aeda92dc7e423820166a6d785e5f101fo.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
myOperation[func_][a_, b_] := 
 If[Length@a == Length@b != 0 && Head[a] =!= Style, 
  MapThread[myOperation[func], {a, b}], func[a, b]]
myDivide[x_, y_] := x/y;
myDivide[Style[x_, c_], y_] := Style[x/y, c];
myDivide[x_, Style[y_, c_]] := Style[x/y, c];
myDivide[Style[x_, c1_], Style[y_, c2_]] := 
 Style[x/y, Blend[{c1, c2}]]

myOperation[
  myDivide] @@ {{{1, 2}, {Style[3, Red], Style[4, Blue]}, {5, 
    6}}, {{7, 8}, {Style[9, Blue], 10}, {Style[11, Cyan], 12}}}
```

I first created `myOperation` to apply a function into a nested list, then create `myDivide` function to implement my form of divide with styling. Will the result be satisfying?

[image: result]